# WCF Datacontract and XML member

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0, xml-serialization

I have a WCF DataContract member whose content should come from a stored procedure returning a XML (using FOR XML statement). This content is dynamic so I can't create contract classes for these entities.I need to attach this Xml to the main Contract class.

Is there a way to have a field like that in WCF? If yes what type am I supposed to use?

I guess I'm not allowed to have XmlDocument/XmlElement class as member type, I'm now trying use generic or object type but with no luck.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Use `XElement` for that member. It will be represented as `xsd:any` in contract description and it will be allowed passing dynamic XML.

Comment: Thanks @Ladislav,it makes sense as I see from WCF reference that XElement is an allowed type, but if I add a XElement DataMember to the contract class the service stops working.